# IF... Else + JOption, Why aren't my JOptionPanes showing?

Tags: if-statement, joptionpane

Problem:
So the first windows shows up asking what day it is. I type in the day and the only thing that pops up is the error message telling me to check my spelling and punctuation. Why aren't the windows with the actual soups of the day showing up?

//*****************************************************************************

public class IfSoupDay {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {


    String day = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"I am going to tell you"
            + " what the soup of the day is."+ "\n"
            + "\n"+"What day of the week is it?");


 if (day == "Monday")   
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The soup of the day is Lobster Soup");


 else if(day == "Tuesday")
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The soup of the day is Potato Soup");

 else if (day == "Wednesday")
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The soup of the day is Chicken Noodle Soup");

 else if (day == "Thursday")
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The soup of the day is Goat Soup");

 else if (day == "Friday")
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The soup of the day is Booty Chunks");

 else if (day == "Saturday" || day == "Sunday")
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry we are closed", "Closed",
             JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

     else
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Be sure to check spelling and punctuation "
             + "such as capitals", "Sorry, not a day", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);


}//end main
```

}

Comment: Try using .equals instead of ==. It is the proper way to compare strings in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing the String literal with a reference.

Use `day.equals("Monday")` instead of `day == "Monday"`

This is a consequence of how Strings are implemented in Java, as it is comparing the hash code of the String literal in your code, which are not the same.

For instance, take two Strings:

```
String lol  = "lol";
String lol2 = "lol";

System.out.println( (lol == lol2) ); // This prints "False"
System.out.println( lol.equals(lol2) ); // This prints "True"
```

When you directly compare any object (`String`, being a capital class is an object rather than a primitive like an `int` or `float` or `char`) with another object, it does not compare what is inside the object. Rather, it compares the hash code such that you are comparing two different references.

`lol` and `lol2` may both print `lol` but just because they have the same contents does not mean that they are the same "containers" so to speak. This is relevant because your code uses a String literal which has its own hash code that Java must reference for comparison.

It is the `.equals()` method that allows Java to compare a String against a String, because doing so must be done in sequence, character by character. This is a result of the underlying C, and how C approaches Strings although there are fundamental differences between C and Java strings.

Comparing a string in C (`char *`), for instance, would only compare the value of the pointer to the first character to the pointer of the first character in the `char *` of the comparison. So the result for comparing `char * lol` and `char * lol2` via `==` equivalence operators is essentially the same in C, with subtle differences (hash code, Object String in Java, etc.)

It's important to understand fully why this is the case, because it is essentially one of the cornerstone concepts in *pass-by-reference* object-oriented programming.

Answer (score 0):

Ok with a little more research I found out that I had to use the equals method in the if parenthesis but I an unsure to why that is if anyone could help me understand that would be cool.